# Post file from Android to Asp.NET Server using HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, httppostedfile

Till now, I was converting image to `Base64String` and then send it to Asp.NET server and convert it to image there. But recently, I came to know that `HttpPostelFile` is good method for it. I `Google` for some example but din't get anyone.

Please anyone help me to upload file from Android Device to Asp.NET Server using `HttpPostedFile` or any another good method.

**I want it using Asp.NET Web Service.**

Comment: means you want to upload image file to server using PHP web-service. Is this what you are asking???

Comment: not PHP Web Service but asp.net webservice.